# A statement that has the same indentation with its previous "if" statement will always be executed?

Tags: python

I'm attending an online course on Python.

```
if <TestExpression>:
    <block>
i=21
```

Regarding the above code ("code1"), the lecturer said that `i=21` will execute, whether or not the test expression is true, because `i=21` has the same indentation with the `if` statement, meaning `i=21` is not part of the `if` statement.

However, the lecturer also said the following code ("code2"):

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return a
    return b
```

is the same as the following code ("code3"):

```
def bigger(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

Doesn't this contradict what he previously said? `i=21` in code1 and `return b` in code2 both have the same indentation with their previous `if` statements, but why `i=21` will always execute no matter the test expression is true or false, while `return b` will execute only when the test expression (a>b) is false?

How do you decide whether the statement immediately following the `if` construct which has the same indentation with the `if` line should execute? In another word, how do you decide whether that statement is part of the `if` construct?

Comment: The difference is due to you using functions. If it reaches a `return` statement then the function will return (stop) straight away regardless of what is after it.

Comment: Just to remind myself: return may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition, according to the [Python reference manual](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/return.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question you have asked, and it's an issue a lot of new people have with functions specifically.

The issue lies with the `return` keyword. In a function, when it `returns` a value, the function immediately breaks. Thus, no subsequent code in the function is run. Because of this, we can short-hand our conditional statements to:

```
if a > b:
    return a
    # Function breaks here - no more code is executed.
# This bit is never reached if a is returned
return b
```

---

Observe:

```
def test():
    if 10 > 5:
        print("Hello!")
        return True
    print("Hi!")
    return False
```

When we call `test()`, only `Hello!` is printed.

---

One reason this is helpful is to stop erroneous whitespace when having multiple conditional statements in Python. Of course, in most other programming languages, since whitespace isn't a feature, it's not as necessary.

Imagine you were writing a function to check if a number was prime, where lots of conditional statements were required. (Of course, for the sake of this example, this isn't efficient):

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    else:
        if n == 2:
            return True
        else:
            for i in range(2, n):
                if n % i == 0:
                    return False # A factor exists
                else:
                    continue
            return True
```

Knowing that a `return` breaks the function, we can re-write this as:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True:
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False # A factor exists
    return True
```

See how the indentation is so much cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can't return twice from a function. When `if` is satisfied, it will return and won't execute any more statement. So, the next `return` statement is unreachable.

The next `return` will only execute when `if` is failed. `else` is also executed when `if` is failed.

That's why your teacher says, both of them are same.